# How to acquire an XML node value using SQL without the WITH XMLNAMESPACES Clause using the value() method?

Tags: sql, xml

This one seems fairly simple at first but the caveat is the XML data must be part of a SQL statement that includes non-XML data fields.

Given the following XML stored in a field called XMLData:

**SAMPLE 1**

```
<rtEvent>
  <ctx>
    <LEAD_ID>3933667137</LEAD_ID>
    <SALE_ID>6098929</SALE_ID>
  </ctx>
</rtEvent>
```

I can acquire the value of any node in the XML structure using the value() method of the SQL XML query and combine it with any other non-XML fields in the returned set in a single statement:

```
SELECT XMLData.value('(/rtEvent/ctx/LEAD_ID)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') LeadId, 
       RecordNo, ProspectName 
FROM SampleData
```

But adding a namespace to the XML structure adds a bit more complexity and what worked previously is no longer an option as the query must now account for the namespace attribute.

**SAMPLE 2**

```
<rtEvent>
  <ctx xmlns="urn:xtk:queryDef">
    <LEAD_ID>906320142</LEAD_ID>
    <SALE_ID>6537962</SALE_ID>
  </ctx>
</rtEvent>
```

If all I needed to retrieve was the value of the LEAD_ID, I believe the options would be more obvious as I could use the WITH XMLNAMESPACES clause prior to the query but I don't see that to work when I need the specific VALUE from the XML structure as part of the total query which would include other fields in the record(s). And placing the required clause before the query doesn't give the result I'm expecting. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

How would I acquire the LEAD_ID value from the second example?

Here is what I've tried and the resulting values are all NULL:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:xtk:queryDef' as ns)
SELECT XMLDat.value('rtEvent/ns:ctx/LEAD_ID[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') LeadId, 
       RecordNo, ProspectName 
FROM SampleData
```

Comment: `CAST(REPLACE(col,'xmlns="urn:xtk:queryDef"', '') AS XML)`

Comment: That is a very shrewd approach and may be what I'll consider but I wanted to know if there was a way to retrieve the value without removing the namespace. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinSmith My apology, you are correct. It was actually an error in my code when I attempted to use the clause. It doesn't thrown an error but trying it again I don't get the desired result either. I'll update the question with the code I've tried

Comment: @MartinSmith I moved the namespace to the root of the XML structure in the example thinking it may have simplified the answer (while you were posting your answer). If you'd like to place your proposed answer back I'd gladly give you credit. If not, no worries. It seems my change posed somewhat of an aggravation you. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML has a default namespace, but your root element `<rtEvent>` is not living within. This default namespace is valid for `<ctx>` **and all nested elements**:

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @mockTable TABLE(XMLDat XML);
INSERT INTO @mockTable VALUES
(
N'<rtEvent>
  <ctx xmlns="urn:xtk:queryDef">
    <LEAD_ID>906320142</LEAD_ID>
    <SALE_ID>6537962</SALE_ID>
  </ctx>
</rtEvent>'
);

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:xtk:queryDef' as ns)
SELECT XMLDat.value('(rtEvent/ns:ctx/ns:LEAD_ID)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') LeadId
FROM @mockTable t;
```

Some things to know:

- Your own approach did miss the `ns:` in front of `LEAD_ID`
- Your own approach uses `[1]` after `LEAD_ID`, but you must use `(somexpath)[1]` to guarantee the *singleton* value. There might be several `<ctx>` elements...
- The element `<rtEvents>` has no namespace at all

Alternatively you might use a wildcard like here:

```
SELECT XMLDat.value('(*:rtEvent/*:ctx/*:LEAD_ID)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') LeadId
FROM @mockTable t
```

But this approach is prone to erros with ambiguity and the general advise is: *Be as specific as possible*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the additional comments provided. This is what I was looking for